# Shuffled order of bytes in gdb when using perl print statement in ubuntu

Tags: perl, ubuntu, gdb, buffer-overflow

```
run $(perl -e 'print "\xfd\x06\x40\x00" x 10')
```

When I run my program with this argument I should get 0x004006fd as the word in the stack but instead I get a rearranged order of this word but never the correct one as show below -:

```
 0x7fffffffde00:    0xfd4006fd  0x06fd4006  0x4006fd40  0xfd4006fd
 0x7fffffffde10:    0x06fd4006  0x4006fd40  0xfd4006fd
```

Here 0x00 is not just coming , I dont know what should be used to write this byte.
I have even tried

```
  run $(perl -e 'print pack("V",0x004006fd) x 10')
```

but no help.
I am really new at this thing , please help. 
I don't even now if I have to do some setting in my ubuntu terminal or where the problem lies.

Comment: What does `perl -e 'print ("\xfd\x06\x40\x00" x 2)' | hexdump -C` gives you? I am getting `00000000  fd 06 40 00 fd 06 40 00` which looks ok

Comment: To answer your question, it is necessary to know what your program does with `argv[1]`.

Comment: @HåkonHægland that gives me correct output the problem occurs when I am trying to buffer overflow in gdb.

Comment: @EmployedRussian argv[1] is passed to a function as an arguement and then it's content is copied into a local char[] variable (via strcpy ) which I want to overflow till I fill the desired adress with return adress. 
Actually I am following Hacking the Art of exploitation.

Comment: If you're viewing data as a stream of 4-byte words instead of a stream of bytes, you'll need to take into account the [endianness](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the CPU. Is your CPU big-endian or little-endian?

Comment: It is little endian

Comment: There you go, then. If you type `x/28bx` instead of `x/7wx`, you'll see the bytes in the same order you wrote them. The 0 bytes were swallowed up by the shell when you did the `$(...)` command substitution.

Comment: Yeah , thanks I actually understood the concept . I need not read the \x00 byte but "\xfd\x06\x40" would be enough and the zero bytes will be filled automatically on that word.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These produce `FD 06 40 00`:

```
"\xFD\x06\x40\x00"
pack("N", 0xFD064000)
pack("V", 0x004006FD)
```

These produce `00 40 06 FD`:

```
"\x00\x40\x06\xFD"
pack("N", 0x004006FD)
pack("V", 0xFD064000)
```

---

Note that command-line arguments are NUL-terminated strings, so it's not possible to pass either of the following strings as a command-line argument:

```
FD 06 40 00 FD 06 40 00 ...       # Passes FD 06 40 00
```

or

```
00 40 06 FD 00 40 06 FD ...       # Passes 00
```

Maybe you should rewrite `run` to accept data as hex, or to accept data from the STDIN.